# How to show map by using table coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary

Having a random coordinates table, how to use onclick to display the location on google map when I click the row. the map will be changed if I click the different row
 the table code is like this,  how can I use the latitude and longitude to use the google

mapProp= {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude),
    zoom:10,
  };

```
for (i = 0; i<11; i++){
var randomla =Math.round((Math.random()*360 - 180) * 1000)/1000;
var randomlo = Math.round((Math.random()*360 - 180) * 1000)/1000



var table = document.getElementById("demo");
var row = table.insertRow(1);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);


cell1.innerHTML = randomla;
cell2.innerHTML = randomlo;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem can be broken into two parts:

#### Attaching `onClick` or `onMouseOver` behaviour to your table cells

You may want to place anchor tags in the cells which link to your google maps url.

You may instead want to attach event handlers to your table rows:

```
var randomla =Math.round((Math.random()*360 - 180) * 1000)/1000;
var randomlo = Math.round((Math.random()*360 - 180) * 1000)/1000
...
var row = table.insertRow(1);
row.addEventListener("click", function(e.target) {
  window.open("GOOGLEURL");
});
```

#### Opening the correct url on google maps.

`https://www.google.com/maps/@LAT,LONG,ZOOMz`

where `LAT` and `LONG` are set to your latitude and longitude and `ZOOM` is set to the zoom level.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake on the random table. There is a random table, and  my question is how to use onlick for each row to have the location on showed map